# How to extract an image from an email in Gnus?

Tags: gnus, images

A friend sent me an email with a JPEG photo in the middle of the text. The picture is so big, most of it is outside the screen and I want to view it with an outside image viewer and not in Gnus. How do I save an image that is included in the email in Gnus, if it's not just an ordinary attachment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The command you need is [`gnus-summary-save-parts`](http://gnus.org/manual/gnus_49.html#index-X-m-_0028Summary_0029). You have an *inline* image, which implies that you received an HTML mail. An inline image is an instance of a so-called [MIME](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIME) part, where MIME is an Internet standard governing email-related things such as non-text attachments.

To read more on how to work with MIME parts in Gnus, read Gnus manual chapters [3.19 MIME Commands](http://gnus.org/manual/gnus_49.html#MIME-Commands), [4.2 Using MIME](http://gnus.org/manual/gnus_65.html#Using-MIME), and also EmacsWiki page [Mime Types With Gnus](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/MimeTypesWithGnus).